# Export to CSV using php

Tags: php, export-to-csv

this is my first time am trying to export the data into csv can anyone tell me how to do it below is my code i tried myself but its not working ,

it just printing the header in cvs file not printing the data in the cvs can anyone guide me where i am wrong.......

Thnaks

Filterdata.php

```
<?php

$mediaexport=$_GET["media"];

?>

<form action = "cmsexp_to_excel.php" method = "post">
<input checked type='checkbox' name="media"  value="<?php echo $mediaexport;?>" style='visibility:hidden' >
<input type="image" value="" src="/img/export.png" class="export" style='margin:0 5px -9px 183px;cursor:pointer;'>
</form>
```

cmsexp_to_excel.php

```
    <?php


    $dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
    $dbUsername = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $dbPassword = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    $dbDatabase = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    $db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) ;
    mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) ;

    $mediaexport=$_GET["media"];

     $values = "SELECT DISTINCT contact.`id` , contact.`contactgroup` , contact.`media` , contact.`media2` , contact.`email1` , contact.`nationality` , contact.`country3` , contact.`twon` , contact.`area` , contact.`gender` , contact.`married` , contact.`children` , contact.`driverslicense`
    FROM contact";

   $header = "Media" . "\t";
$header .= "E-mail" . "\t";
$header .= "Nationality" . "\t";
$header .= "City" . "\t";

while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)){


$row1[] = $row['media'];
$row1[] = $row['email1'];
$row1[] = $row['ntionality'];
$row1[] = $row['city'];

$data .= join(',', $row1)."\n";

}
header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Inbox-Reprot.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data"; 
exit();

    ?>
```

Comment: `but its not working` is not a useful description of a problem. What is happening? What debugging have you done? What errors is your code generating (such as "Use of undefined constant Test assumed 'Test'") ?

Comment: its only opening an filen

Comment: Here's a piece of code that works: https://gist.github.com/tracend/3133975

Comment: It's better to use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function than create your own CSV writer

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a multidimensional array, like this:

```
$my_array = array(
  array("First Name", "Last Name", "Address", "City"),
  array("Marty", "McFly", "9303 Lyon Drive", "Hill Valley"),
  array("Emmett", "Brown", "1640 Riverside Drive", "Hill Valley")
);
```

So, you should set the header to `application/csv`, and `echo` all the values in the array, separated with a comma:

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=your_file_name.csv");

foreach ($my_array as $row) {
  echo implode(",", $row) . "\r\n";
}
```

PHPFiddle link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v2w6-cxv9